# How to record who edited a table in my sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a function to automatically update a column specifying who created a new record in a sql table?

Something similar to the timestamp, but that instead of the time it shows the user who has added the record.

e.g.

```
value user  
111   Luis  
111   Admin  
112   Luis
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with MySQL itself you cannot do it. The only user known by MySql is the `current_user()` which the application uses to connect.

you can create Trigger in order to save this user but I believe this does not worth much

```
created_by varchar(100);
create trigger table_insert_trig before insert on table for each row begin set new.created_by := current_user(); end;
```

Another option is to pass current_user from your application using your Data Access Layer, but this is unrelated with MySql itself and it is Application Logic.